# Activity on questions not updated with click of "questions with new activity"

Tags: bug, live-refresh

I've noticed that, (at least on StackOverflow), when clicking on the "`x questions with new activity`" banner at the top of my feed, the questions are appended to the top of the page, but what comes up doesn't reflect any activity *within* those questions.

In particular, I sometimes find after entering a question that it's already been answered, it's already been downvoted to hell, or that it's been put on hold, etc., each of which feel like a waste of time in their own right.

This is especially salient if I happen to have left a feed tab open overnight -- by the time I get there, most of those questions have been dealt with by others in the community.

This is fixed with a simple page refresh -- but IIUC, the point of having the banner is to avoid the need to refresh.

## Example:

### Banner Active:

[image]

---

### Banner Clicked:

[image]

All new questions suspiciously have 1 view, no activity

---

### Hit refresh:

[image]

Views updated, 4th question down got an answer. Whole sequence above performed in < 10 seconds.